# What does mean "Six a year" in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The number of historical novels published in Canada is very low. ***Six a
>   year*** is the number I was given.

What does it mean "Six a year" in here?

Comment: It means *six historical novels per year*, which means that there are normally six historical novels that are published in Canada in a year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that there are six historical novels published in Canada per year.  One of the [definitions of *a*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/a) is:

> ***preposition***
>   each; every; per: ten cents a sheet; three times a day.